# hello world does not work properly in html with jointjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jointjs

I am a beginner in html and the joint.js library. I have this code and once I saved it as html on my laptop, it is suppose to draw 2 connected rectangles but nothing appears in the browser.
I downloaded many libraries and put them in the same folder that has the html page but nothing appear too.

What am I suppose to do?
Where can I put the libraries that I want to use in html code?

The libraries that I downloaded are:

- backbone.js
- core.js
- geometry.js
- joint.all.css
- joint.all.js
- joint.all.min.css
- joint.all.min.js
- joint.css
- joint.dia.cell.js
- joint.dia.element.js
- joint.dia.graph.js
- joint.dia.link.js
- joint.dia.paper.js
- joint.js
- joint.min.css
- joint.min.js
- joint.shapes.devs.js
- joint.shapes.devs.min.js
- joint.shapes.erd.js
- joint.shapes.erd.min.js
- joint.shapes.fsa.js
- joint.shapes.fsa.min.js
- joint.shapes.org.js
- joint.shapes.org.min.js
- jquery.js
- jquery.sortElements.js
- lodash.js
- raphael-min.js
- raphael.js
- vectorizer.js

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="joint.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="joint.js" ></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {    
      var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

      var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
           el: $('#myholder'),
           width: 600,
           height: 200,
           model: graph
      });

      var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
           position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
           size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
           attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
      });

      var rect2 = rect.clone();
      rect2.translate(300);

      var link = new joint.dia.Link({
           source: { id: rect.id },
           target: { id: rect2.id }
      });
         graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
  })           
  </script>


  <div id="myholder" >
  </div>
  ```

---

**Thanks to all of you ..
The program is working now after I changed the source of the libraries to be website URLs. If I use the once that I downloaded on my computer it does not work again :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src= "http://denknix.com/astro/lib/joint/www/build/joint.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jointjs.com/downloads/joint.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jointjs.com/downloads/joint.js" ></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

        var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
             el: $('#myholder'),
             width: 600,
             height: 200,
             model: graph
        });

        var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
             position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
             size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
             attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
        });

        var rect2 = rect.clone();
        rect2.translate(300);

        var link = new joint.dia.Link({
             source: { id: rect.id },
             target: { id: rect2.id }
        });
graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
    })     
    </script>

    <title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="myholder" >
    </div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: check to see if your javascript file is being loaded and there are no errors while it is being loaded. Just hit F12 on your browser and look at the console there should usually be an error if there is a problem loading the javascript of if the location of it is not found.

Comment: hello @Gjohn : my laptop is mac > which button should I press ?

Comment: are you running the site in safari? What browser are you using? if you are using safari, follow the following steps to enable the develop menu http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/safaridevelop.htm. Once you enable it select show error console and refresh your site

Comment: @Gjohn I have tried google chrome and safari .. Both of the did not give me the supposed output. I thought about having mistake of placing the libraries.. since I put all of them with the html file inside a folder in the desktop

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of your `$(function() {` call. Should be `});` at the end.

Comment: @Gjohn I did what you told me in safari : I got this errors:[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (joint.all-min.js, line 0)
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (joint.js, line 4)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
 global code (testing2.html, line 9)

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot I added the ; but nothing change ;(

Comment: Your code seems to work (ie. does something). E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/m4Sdu/2/

Comment: @veritasetratio yes when I try any code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) it works but when I write it as an html code on my computer it does not work .. I do not know why!!

Comment: Yep, that is because it did not load query so of course $ is not going to be available. You need to add a reference to Jquery.js before your joint.js reference

Comment: @Gjohn how can I add the reference ? what should I write ?

Comment: @Gjohn I added this reference : <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>        . Nothing change

Comment: thanks @Gjohn for giving me some of your time ..

Comment: thanks @veritasetratio and for giving me some of your time ..

Comment: thanks @ElliotSchmelliot for giving me some of your time ..

Comment: @Nada No Problem,  you can probably get it working with the local script store. Perhaps try putting all the scripts in a Javascript folder and then reference it in your code like <script src="/Javascript/Jquery.js"....

Answer (score 2):

Note that you don't need the following two files in your example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src= "http://denknix.com/astro/lib/joint/www/build/joint.all.min.js"></script>
```

This is because jQuery is already included in `joint.js` and the other `joint.all.min.js` is a very old version of JointJS (0.4).

You only need the other two files that you have correctly included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jointjs.com/downloads/joint.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jointjs.com/downloads/joint.js" ></script>
```

The problem must lie in how you reference those files once download them to your computer.

Comment: Thank you very much @dave I appreciate your answer.. I would like to ask you if there is a clear documentation on JointJS or any materials to understand the functions ?? I am very intrested in this library and mostly it will help me on my study project.

Comment: @Nada, the API of JointJS is documented here: http://jointjs.com/api, tutorial and getting started guide is here: http://jointjs.com/tutorial, you can also learn from the source code of the demos: http://jointjs.com/demos. Discussions with further info is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jointjs and on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jointjs.